# Cut/Paste with PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a 1004 error when I try and cut and paste a range

```
Sub TEST_Code()

Dim wsMRU, wsCov As Worksheet

Set wsCov = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Page")
Set wsMRU = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MRU Calcs")

With wsMRU
    .Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Cut
    .Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Basically, the values that are copied are not staying in the clipboard and I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cut` method doesn't work with `PasteSpecial`. It needs a `Destination`.

```
Sub TEST_Code()
    ' 045

    ' you must specify the data type for each variable(!)
    Dim wsMRU As Worksheet, wsCov As Worksheet
    
    Set wsCov = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Page")
    Set wsMRU = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MRU Calcs")
    
    With wsMRU
        .Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Cut Destination:=.Cells(4, "B")
    End With
End Sub
```

I recommend to use the syntax for addressing cells to address cells and limit the syntax for addressing ranges to address ranges of cells. That would imply `.Cells(4, "A").CurrentRegion.Cut Destination:=.Cells(4, "B")`